# Errors for building Tensorflow 1.8 from sources for C/C++ on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, tensorflow

When compiling Tensorflow from source with the following commands

```
brew install automake libtool
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow && cd tensorflow
git checkout r1.8
export ANDROID_TYPES="-D__ANDROID_TYPES_FULL__"
tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh
```

The following errors were thrown

```
In file included from         /Users/xxx/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/ThreadPool:58:
 /Users/xxx/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/ThreadPool/SimpleThreadPool.h:153:5: error: 
  thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
EIGEN_THREAD_LOCAL PerThread per_thread;
/Users/xxx/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/ThreadPool/ThreadLocal.h:15:35: note: 
  expanded from macro 'EIGEN_THREAD_LOCAL'
#define EIGEN_THREAD_LOCAL static __thread
```

Is there any solution to fix this error? I tried to remove the whole folder and clone again but results the same error.

Comment: I got the same error when building r1.10. It will be great if anyone has any clue.